# iTunes components on top of NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes

What components one should use to recreate the iTunes controls that are located on the top of the Window, specifically the playable buttons and the box that overrides the title by showing artist and track information? Is it a component like NSToolbox or it's a custom view?[image: iTunes controls]

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a customization of the title bar.  To pull of something similar in my app, I've been using [this project](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow). It'll let you change the size of the title bar and include various buttons.

Comment: I've seen the component in github, I didn't test it, but seems that the close/minimize/maximize controls would be at the middle of the Titlebar. I upvoted the answer, I'll mark it as correct if the control suggested works. Thank you very much

Comment: Not necessarily...personally I hate the aesthetics of that, and in my implementation those controls are still in the top left. You can set that with the property (BOOL) centerTrafficLightButtons.

Comment: If you check out the way tabular implements their class, it looks very much like the effect you're working towards...except with the centered buttons. http://chromaticlabs.com/tabular/